# Ubuntu 20.04 USB Headphones not working and not showed in pulse audio

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I connected my USB headphones to the PC. However I cannot pick the sound option in pulse audio settings.

However when I run this command:

```
arecord --list-devices
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC257 Analog [ALC257 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Headset [Logitech USB Headset], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I can see that teh device is available. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you `pkill -U $USER pulseaudio` to restart pulseaudio and see if the headset is picked up? It's not a great solution, but it will let you know whether the service can use the headset at all.

Comment: Post your question up on [this thread](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewforum.php?f=90&sid=512d36abcdf716ee304a5a112ae93ec7). Although it's a LM forum there are a couple of audio experts there who will crack it for you in no time. You'll need to register.